# Owned resource in JAX-RS

Tags: jaxb, jax-rs

I'm trying to understand REST and JAX-RS / JAXB, I have many-to-many relationship beetwen Libraries and Books. I wanna make GET-POST-PUT-DELETE operations on a book that is owned by a library, so the url for a GET is "libraries/{library_id}/books/{book_id}" 
I've implemented it in this way:

```
@Stateless
@Path("libraries")
public class LibraryFacadeREST extends AbstractFacade<Library> {

  ...    

   @Path("{library_id}/booksFacade/")
   public BookFacadeREST getBookFacade() {
     return bookFacadeREST;
    }
  ...
}

@Stateless
@Path("books")
public class BookFacadeREST extends AbstractFacade<Book> {
   ...
    @GET
    @Path("{id}")
    @Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
    public Book find(@PathParam("id") Long id, @PathParam("library_id") long libraryId) {

       Book book = super.find(id);

       if (libraryId != -1) {
          Library library = em.find(Library.class, libraryId);

          if (book.getLibraries().contains(library)) {
             return book;
          } else {
             return null;
          }
       }

      return null;
   }
   ...
}
```

But I don't like it, it sucks, are there better ways for managing owned resources in jaxrs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why rest resources need relationship just because the according entities have relationship? 
I think the book resource should in this way:

```
@Path("libraries/{library_id}/books")
public class BookFacadeREST extends AbstractFacade<Book> {
    @GET
    @Path("{id}")
    @Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
    public Book find(@PathParam("id") Long id, @PathParam("library_id") long libraryId) {
       ...
    }
}
```

Comment: yep, I'm thinking the same. In this way the classes are more readable.